# Cant create an Otp Login with Supabase

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, supabase, next.js13

I am having a Hardtime with Supabase.

whenever I try using the docs info to work on my page I get this error

[image: error message]

but according to the docs this is what they asked me to do

```
import { createPagesBrowserClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { SessionContextProvider } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Create a new supabase browser client on every first render.
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createPagesBrowserClient())

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionContextProvider>
  )
}
```

which i did the same [image: my code]

Yet I am having an error, please help out!

I have googled for several solutions, yet I havent seen any.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I had to add this

```js
import { createPagesBrowserClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { SessionContextProvider } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import AppLayout from "src/core/layouts/App";
import "src/styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createPagesBrowserClient());
  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <AppLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AppLayout>
    </SessionContextProvider>
  );
}
```

but this error arose again

[image: new error]

Comment: It's likely you aren't on the version of the auth-helpers that has that function. This function was introduced in @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs 0.7.0. If you installed this then you should try deleting your `node_modules` and your `.next` directories in your project and try to install it again.